# Sync over Async generic methods. How ExecSync call ExecAsync?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

You work with latest and greatest lucky you!!. Some of us have no options but support legacy code that we cannot modify etc..
We cannot do async all the way....

So sync over async in an old asp.net mvc4 web application and following this article [Brownfield Async Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development) and a previous post of mine

It suggests doing something like below to avoid deadlock.

```
public SomeStuff GetSomestuff(Whatever whatever)
{
    return GetSomestuffAsync(whatever).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

public async Task<SomeStuff> GetSomestuffAsync(Whatever whatever)
{
    // Do NOT queue a synchronization context continuation.
    return myRefitHttpClient.GetSomestuff(whatever).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

My question:

I want to make 2 generic methods - `ExecAsync` and `ExecSync` so that I drastically reduce the code I need to write. I have the the following (removed logging etc.. )

```
    public async Task ExecAsync<T>(
        Func<Task<T>> method,
        Action<T> response)
    {
        T result = await method.Invoke().ConfigureAwait(false);
        response(result);
    }
```

But now I want the "Sync version calling the async one" but cannot get it compile/working

```
    public void ExecSync<T>(
        Func<Task<T>> method,
        Action<T> response)
    {
         //BELOW IS WRONG! I need to call Async and then GetAwaiter().GetResult()
        //ExecAsync(()=>method, r => response = r).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        //response(r);
    }
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Find this code below : is below a decent solution for sync over async

Microsoft built an `AsyncHelper` (internal) class to run Async as Sync.
The source looks like:

```
internal static class AsyncHelper
{
    private static readonly TaskFactory _myTaskFactory = new 
       TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None, 
              TaskCreationOptions.None, 
              TaskContinuationOptions.None, 
              TaskScheduler.Default);

  public static void RunSync(Func<Task> task)
    {
        //Storing the context
        var storeContext = HttpContext.Current;

        taskFactory
            .StartNew(task)
            .Unwrap()
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
       //restoring context
        HttpContext.Current = storeContext;
    }


    public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> task)
    {
        var storeContext = HttpContext.Current;

        var result= taskFactory
            .StartNew(task)
            .Unwrap()
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult(); 
        //restoring context
        HttpContext.Current = storeContext;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `ExecAsync(method, response).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: @shingo does not compile - can you show full snippet

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AxlSSE

Comment: `return GetSomestuffAsync(whatever).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` <-- Uhhh, this is exactly how you can trigger a deadlock... I'm not sure how this is supposed to help you avoid it.

Comment: @Dai what I wrote in my question already avoids deadloack but I dont want to write 100s of GetSomestuff and GetSomestuffAsync, I want to wrap it up

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question. You are welcome to answer your own question.

Comment: @Charlieface I dont have a solution I am still looking for a solution - What I wrote in the update I am not sure is the correct way of doing things and wanted some feedback

Comment: What's the purpose of passing `response`? Why not just call async methods normally? And for sync, you can just use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, as mentioned, or the `AsyncHelper`. Not sure what your question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cannot get it compile/working

Getting it to compile is easy enough:

```
public void ExecSync<T>(Func<Task<T>> method, Action<T> response)
{
  ExecAsync(method, response).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

However, getting it *working* is more of a challenge.

You are asking for a generic, general-purpose sync-over-async solution. This **does not exist**. If it did, then articles like Brownfield Async wouldn't have been written; everyone could just use the generic solution and be done with it.

The current solution assumes that your code uses `ConfigureAwait(false)` for every `await` in your app. If it does, then fine.

Another solution is the thread pool hack, but that one assumes that the code can run on any arbitrary thread pool thread. On old ASP.NET code, this may not be the case; in particular code that accesses `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: finally yes I was looking for a generic "sync over async". Ok does not exists.At least I can move on now. So I have an old asp.net mvc 4  that currently uses soap and moving to https calls to a restapi. So far I was going  is to use AsyncHelper and do something like "var response AsyncHelpers.RunSync(myRefitApi.GetSomethingAsync); My question is this the best I can possibly do?  Or do you do something else in  your nuget? Regarding configureAwait False , Does it matter in an asp.net mvc if I dont use it? Kind of confused what my best option is. Any further clarification would be helpful !!

Comment: Am I right in saying that due to HttpContext.Current being used all over the shop in this mvc app I am working on, I should remove "ConfigureAwait(false) as it loses the HttpContext?  So In conclusion I should have 2 methods for each call  a sync method calling an async method and remove ConfigureAwait(false)? I Cannot possibly analyse all the calls so I will not use ConfigureAwait(false) problem solved no?

Comment: I am not familiar with your library Stephen, do you have a "RunSync" that does not loose the HttpContext and does not block? or see my edited soluton for AsyncHelpers about storing the context. WIll that work?

Comment: Yes, `ConfigureAwait(false)` will lose `HttpContext.Current`. The `AsyncHelpers` approach as currently posted won't work, because it won't keep the` HttpContext.Current` set *within* the delegate posted to the thread pool. Even if you changed the code so it was set/cleared as part of the delegate, it still wouldn't be a good idea because `HttpContext` is not threadsafe.

Comment: You're in the worst possible situation, unfortunately, because many of the sync-over-async hacks won't work. Due to the `HttpContext.Current` usage, you can't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` and you also can't shunt the work to a thread pool thread. You *can* try using a single-threaded context (`AsyncContext.Run` in my AsyncEx library), but beware: some ASP.NET APIs will be broken with this context; in my experience, they don't throw but will hang. It's worth a shot, though, if you can't take the time to make it all *properly* asynchronous.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and input Stephen, what about if I cache the httpcurrentContext before each call and than restore it? If I were to make this old mvc site properly asyncrous from controllers till it calls the rest api do I still need to remove the HttpContext.Current? What about just the HttpContext ? Not just current Many thanks

Comment: `HttpContext` itself isn't thread safe. You could pull all the data you need out of it and store it elsewhere for the rest of the code to use, if all the access is read-only.